# QGIS temporary layer to PostGIS table database

Tags: postgis, pyqgis, python-2.7

I have an empty polygon table in PostgreSQL/PostGIS database with fields (`id`,`field_1`).

after some processing in QGIS using pyqgis and processing toolbar I create some temporary layer like this case :

```
outputs_GDALOGRPOLYGONIZE_1=processing.runalg('gdalogr:polygonize', raster,'DN',None)
outputs_GDALOGRCLIPVECTORSBYPOLYGON_1=processing.runalg('gdalogr:clipvectorsbypolygon', outputs_GDALOGRPOLYGONIZE_1['OUTPUT'],cut,None,clip)
```

how to add the temporary layer `outputs_GDALOGRPOLYGONIZE_1['OUTPUT']` into the empty polygon table from PostGIS table using pyqgis?